# asp net core startup basic programming understanding

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm new in programming and looking to understand the basics.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

looks like you send a Startup class from your project but **the question is**  How can the other side receives the class , I mean I can't see any relationship between my project Startup and TStartup .

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

```
public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder UseStartup<TStartup> (this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder) where TStartup : class;
```

`where TStartup : class` so it can be any class.